# switch permite float, double? en java

Tags: java, condiciones

Estoy tratando de hacer un código en java que simule el comportamiento de un cajero automático, con 3 opciones que son 1- ingresar dinero, 2- retirar dinero 3- salir. Pero tengo un problema con el switch que me dice que los tipos son incompatibles. El código es el siguiente:

```
package ejercicio7condicionalesats;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Ejercicio7condicionalesAts {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double dinero, dineroingresado, retirardinero, dinerototal =0;

    dinero = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Que desea hacer? \n 1- Ingresar dinero \n 2- Retirar dinero \n 3- Salir"));


    switch(dinero) {

        case '1' : dineroingresado = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite cuanto dinero desea ingresar"));
            System.out.println("El dinero ingresado es de: \n" + dineroingresado);
            System.out.println("El dinero total es de: \n" + dineroingresado + dinerototal);
            break;

        case '2' : retirardinero = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite cuanto desea retirar"));
            if (retirardinero < dinerototal) {

                System.out.println("No puede retirar esa cantidad \n Saldo insuficiente");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Su dinero es:" + (dinerototal - retirardinero));
                System.out.println("Dinero retirado correctamente");
                break;
            }

        case '3' : break;

        default : JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se equivoco de opcion");
            break;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Segun la documentacion, son incompatibles. mira la doc [aca](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). revisa eso, y despues agrega una linda respuesta a tu propia pregunta!

Comment: es requerimiento trabajar con tipos que acepten decimales? no puedes usar int? saludos

Comment: Eso estaba pensando ¿Aceptara un tipo char para seleccionar las opciones?

Comment: @SoraKasugano lo mejor es usar los tipos que indica la documentación.

Comment: si pasas tu double a string para usarlo en el switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) indica:

> Un `switch` funciona con los tipos de datos primitivos `byte`,
>   `short`, `char` e `int`. También funciona con tipos `Enum`, la clase
>   `String` y algunas clases especiales que envuelven ciertos tipos
>   primitivos: `Character`, `Byte`, `Short` e `Integer`.

En este caso no se puede usar Double por la conversion de tipos.

Como ejemplo, imagina si se aceptaran valores `double`, y el valor a usar en tu `switch` para la variable `dinero` fuera:

```
 2.9
```

No podría usar el valor 2.9 para decidir que opción realizar!.

aquí únicamente funcionaría si realizaras un conversión de tipo, lo que conlleva a una perdida por redondeo, ya que realizando el `casting` mediante `(int)dinero` se obtendría:

```
2
```

---

Una opción para corregir el problema es realizar un casting

```
 switch((int)dinero) {
  ...
  ...
  ...
 }
```

pero debes tener en cuenta que tendrías una "conversión con perdida".

Lo ideal es usar uno de los tipos con los que funciona el `switch`.